# wxwidgets: linking to wxMediaCtrl using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxWidgets and the wxMediaCtrl to play some video files. However, I am having issue linking my application with the wxMediaCtrl. I looked at some wxWidgets documentation but it is not clear on what I should do.

So, I have an application using it and in my top level CMakeLists, I use wxWidgets as follows:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base)
INCLUDE(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
```

I think here I should use other libraries too (related to wxMediaCtrl) but have no idea what they are called.

Then I link my app as:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Now, when I do this, I get the linker errors whereever I use wxMediaCtrl as:

```
undefined reference to `wxMediaCtrl::GetPlaybackRate()
undefined reference to `vtable for wxMediaCtrl'
```

And there are multiple instances of these for various methods of wxMediaCtrl.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved by problem by setting:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base media)
```

I had to add the media component as well. I do not know how to get a list of available components in wxWidgets yet.

Comment: You can use `wx-config --help` to see the list of all the available libraries at the end of its output.

Comment: Ahhhh..did not know that utility at all. Thanks!